# Telerik RadGrid with conditional format

Tags: jquery, telerik, grid

I have this Telerik RadGrid with a simple conditional format with jQuery.
Each time I make changes/page switch/filter... I lose my format.
Can I use some event in the grid to call this function and not lose the format?

```
$('td').each(
                function () {
                    var myTD = $(this).text();                   
                    if (myTD.match("^Due")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-green');
                    }
                    if (myTD.match("^Not yet due")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-yellow');
                    }
                    if (myTD.match("^Overdue")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-red');
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm terrible with jQuery, but I know that the RadGrid is causing postbacks and that is clearing the new class for your items in the grid. I think, in jQuery, there is a way to persist through postback. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of RadGrid client events you can use, such as this one.

```
<ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnMasterTableViewCreated="MasterTableViewCreated" />
</ClientSettings>

function MasterTableViewCreated(sender, args){
    applyStyle();
}

function applyStyle(){
    $('td').each(
                function () {
                    var myTD = $(this).text();                   
                    if (myTD.match("^Due")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-green');
                    }
                    if (myTD.match("^Not yet due")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-yellow');
                    }
                    if (myTD.match("^Overdue")) {
                        $(this).addClass('trafic-red');
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Work nicely. Even with grouping and filtering functions on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to use the Grid 'DataBound' event to get the `GridDataItem`.

In this exemple we are going to chance a cell `BackgroundColor` based on a `CheckBox`State:

```
protected void Unnamed_DataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item["BoolGood"].Controls[0];
        TableCell cell = (TableCell)item["BoolGood"];
        cell.BackColor = (chk.Checked ? Color.Green : Color.Red);
    }
}
```

We can apply a `CssClass` to the cell directly:

```
cell.CssClass = "myClass";
```